# how to write this code without using any kind of loops

Tags: arrays, c, switch-statement

I need to write this C code using switch and without using loops i need to remove the 'for' in the question and write something instead to get the same output  all here is the code:

```
 int main()
       {
       int  count=0;
        char arr[7];
        printf("enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s",arr);
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        switch(arr[i]){
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        count++;
        break;
        }
        }
        printf("\nthe number of vowels is: %d",count);
    
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: It is not possible to write a code iterating a string without loops or recursion (well, unless you have a very fixed size input - like this `7` in your program - but that would be pretty stupid exercise in replicating the same code). Are you looking for recursion?

Comment: The professer told us we must not use loops here is the question if you want     
:Write a program that defines an array of 7 characters (string). You need to prompt the user to read the string entered then compute how many vowels in that string. You should use switch statement to solve this question

Comment: I do not see any restriction on loops in this question

Comment: Anyway, explain to your professor, that without using loops you will have to replicate the switch/case block for each character in your string. And ask if that is what he really wants.

Comment: he told us in the lecture

Answer (score 3):

No For-loops, using only switch-case and recursive call.

```
int count_vowels(const char* text)
{
    int vowel = 0;
    switch (toupper(*text))
    {
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
        vowel = 1;
        break;
    }

    return *text ? count_vowels(++text) + vowel : 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char* text = "Hello World";

    int count = count_vowels(text);
    printf("\nthe number of vowels is: %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is so bad, that I strongly doubt an instructor came up with this:

> Write a program that defines an array of 7 characters (string).

Ok, this is easy: `int arr[7];`. The *(string)* is somewhat suspicious, but let's keep going:

> You need to prompt the user to read the string entered

This is definitely unclear, but I guess the meaning is `Prompt the user to enter a string and read it into the previously defined array`.

Anyway, in C we read from files, even if the file is the console. So it's important to clarify how we detect that the user has finished entering a string. You can come up with many different ideas, but a pretty classical one is reading until you find a newline character `\n`.

The only problem is that the array can hold up 7 characters at most, including a 0 to mark the end of the string, meaning that we can read 6 characters at most from standard input.

This can be done with `scanf("%6[^\n]", arr);`

> then compute how many vowels in that string. You should use switch statement to solve this question

Your code uses a loop, but is also plainly wrong, since it doesn't check if `scanf()` was successful and it assumes that the string will have 7 characters in it. A fixed version of your code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int count = 0;
    char arr[7];
    printf("Enter a string (I will keep up to 6 characters): ");
    if (scanf("%6[^\n]", arr) != 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("I'll count the vowels in the zero terminated string \"%s\"\n", arr);
    
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] != 0; i++) {
        switch(arr[i]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of vowels is: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, but you also ask "how to write this code without using any kind of loops", so you get what you ask:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int count = 0;
    char arr[7];
    printf("Enter a string (I will keep up to 6 characters): ");
    if (scanf("%6[^\n]", arr) != 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("I'll count the vowels in the zero terminated string \"%s\"\n", arr);
    
    int i = 0;
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        switch(arr[i++]) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("The number of vowels is: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Shorter with macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define x \
    do if (arr[i]) {                                      \
        switch(arr[i++]) {                                \
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U': \
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': \
            count++;                                      \
        }                                                 \
    } while (0)
#define CHECK_VOWELS { int i = 0; x;x;x;x;x;x; }

int main(void) 
{
    int count = 0;
    char arr[7];
    printf("Enter a string (I will keep up to 6 characters): ");
    if (scanf("%6[^\n]", arr) != 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("I'll count the vowels in the zero terminated string \"%s\"\n", arr);
    
    CHECK_VOWELS

    printf("The number of vowels is: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is to define **what is a loop**, since you ask *without any kind of loop*. Is recursion a loop? If not you could use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_vowels(const char *s)
{
    switch(*s) {
    case 0: return 0;
    case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        return count_vowels(s + 1) + 1;
    default: return count_vowels(s + 1);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char arr[7];
    printf("Enter a string (I will keep up to 6 characters): ");
    if (scanf("%6[^\n]", arr) != 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("I'll count the vowels in the zero terminated string \"%s\"\n", arr);
    printf("The number of vowels is: %d\n", count_vowels(arr));
    return 0;
}
```